# Backwards Heat Equation $ u_{t} = -\lambda^2 u_{xx}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

### Problem

> Consider the backwards heat equation of the form 
>   $$ \left\{ \begin{aligned} u_{t} & = \lambda^2 u_{xx}, & x\in[0,L], \quad t\in[0,T]\\ u(0,t) &= u(L,t) = 0 \\ u(x,T) &= f(x), \end{aligned} \right.\tag{*}\label{*}$$
>   Establish whether solution is unique and analyze its stability.

#### Attempt of (*dis*)proving stability

My attempt to answer the stability question is provided in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284261/229317).

#### Attempt of proving uniqueness

I know that it is possible to use the energy functional method for proving uniqueness of the solution of backwards heat equation in a way we do that for a regular heat equation, with some additional tweaks.

Assume there are two different solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ of $\eqref{*}$ and define the discrepancy as $w(x,t) : = u_1(x,t) - u_2(x,t)$. By superposition principle $w(x,t)$ is also a solution of \eqref{*}.
Define the energy 
$$
E (t):=\int_0^Lw^2(x,t)\,dx \ge 0,
$$
then
$$\dot{E}(t) := \frac{dE}{dt} = 2\int_0^L w  w_t\,dx, = 2 \int_0^L w  w_{xx}\,dx = 2ww_x\big|_{0}^L - 2\int_0^L w_x^2\,dx=-2\int_0^L w_x^2\,dx,$$
$$
\ddot{E}(t) = \frac{d }{dt}\Big(\dot{E}(t) \Big) = -2\frac{d }{dt}\Bigg(\int_0^L w_x^2\,dx \Bigg) = -4\int_0^L w_x w_{xt}\,dx = 4\int_0^L w_{xx} w_{t}\,dx = 4\int_0^L w_{xx}^2 \,dx
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz we have 
$$ \dot{E}^2 = 4\Bigg(\int_0^L w  w_{xx}\Bigg)^2\le 4\bigg(\int_0^Lw^2\,dx \bigg)\cdot \bigg(\int_0^Lw_{xx}^2\,dx\bigg)  = E\cdot \ddot{E}$$

What should be the next step in the proof?

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1285827/229317), I was able to get the following:

$$\dot{E}^2\le E \ddot{E} $$

Define $F(t) := \ln\big(E(t)\big)$, then
$$ \dot{F} = \frac{\dot{E}}{E}, \quad \ddot{F} = \frac{\ddot{E}E - \dot{E}^2}{E^2} > 0, $$
so that $F(t)$ is **convex**. By definition of convexity, 
$$ \forall t_1, t_2 \in [0,T], \ \forall \theta\in [0,1] \quad F\big(\theta t_1 + (1-\theta) t_2 \big) \le \theta F(t_1) + (1-\theta) F(t_2 )  \implies
\\
\ln\Big(E\big(\theta t_1 + (1-\theta) t_2 \big) \Big) \le \theta \ln\big(E(t_1)\big) + (1-\theta)\ln\big(E(t_2)\big) = 
\ln \Big(E^\theta\left( t_1 \right) E^{(1-\theta)}\left( t_2 \right)  \Big)
\\
E\big(\theta t_1 + (1-\theta) t_2 \big) \le E^\theta\left( t_1 \right) E^{(1-\theta)}\left( t_2 \right) 
 $$
Choosing $t_2 = T$ and assuming arbitrary $t_1 = t$, we get 
$$E\big(\theta t + (1-\theta) T \big) \le E^\theta\left( t \right) \underbrace{E^{(1-\theta)}\left( T \right)}_{=0}  =0 \quad \forall \theta \in [0,1]$$
Since $w(T) = u_1(x,T) - u_2(x,T) = 0$, we know that 
$E(T) =0 $.
But then 
$$
0 \le E\big(\theta t_1 + (1-\theta) t_2 \big) \le E^\theta (t)\! \cdot\!0 \implies 
\\
  \forall t\in (0,T) \quad E(t) \equiv 0 \ \implies w(x,t) \equiv 0  \iff
\\
 u_1(x,t) \equiv u_2(x,t).
$$
*Q.E.D.*

Comment: We don't know that $\dot{E}(0) = 0$, we only know that $\dot{E}(T) = 0$, which does not contradict anything so far

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is unique. In the post you linked it is specified that well-posed solution is unique and continuously depends on initial data (i.e. is stable). I am pretty sure that for backwards heat equation  the uniqueness of solution holds, but the stability fails.

Comment: There are two equivalent ways to formulate backwards heat equation:
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} u_t &= -\lambda^2 u_{xx} \\ u(0,t)& = u(L,t) = 0\\ u(x,0)& = f(x)\end{aligned}\right. \iff \left\{ \begin{aligned}  u_t &=\lambda^2 u_{xx} \\ u(0,t)& = u(L,t) = 0\\ u(x,T)& = f(x)\end{aligned}\right.  
$$
I referred the first one in the title of this post, but used the second one in posing the problem and performing calculations.

Comment: Page 12:  http://home.ku.edu.tr/~vkalantarov/math551/m551%28heq%29.pdf . I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $\dot E^2\le E\ddot E$ brings to mind logarithmic differentiation. (I.e., $\dot E/E$ is the derivative of $\log E$.) So, let $\Phi(t)=\log E(t)$ and calculate
$$
\ddot \Phi = \frac{\ddot E}{E}-\frac{\dot E^2}{E^2}
$$
Conclude that $\Phi$ is a convex function of $t$. Therefore, it is impossible for it to drop from a finite value to $-\infty$ in finite time. In terms of $E$, this means if the energy was positive at some moment, it will always be positive.

Comment: This is the first time I see method build on taking *second* derivative of energy